# Rails and Blazer 2 Line Graph

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-6

If anyone is familiar with Blazer / sql, I could really use your assistance:

I'm trying to create a line chart in Blazer
=> https://blazer.dokkuapp.com/queries/5-line-chart-format-2

[graph sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHuoK.png)

I'm wanting to plot the [ qikpac_id ] and [ reading_values.value ]

BUT in need to filter the reading type what is "soc" @

```
WHERE reading_types.value = 'soc'
```

So I end up with 4 columns and I only want

Y axis as reading_values.value

X as reading_time

Qikpacs as plotted value

sql query so far :

```
SELECT
-- ## comented ## date_trunc('minute', reading_time)::date AS minute, 
reading_time,
reading_types.value as Reading_Type,
reading_values.value as Reading_Value,
qikpac_id as Qikpac 
FROM reading_values
INNER JOIN reading_types
ON reading_values.reading_type_id = reading_types.id
JOIN battery_statuses
ON reading_values.battery_status_id = battery_statuses.id
JOIN battery_readings
ON reading_values.battery_reading_id = battery_readings.id
WHERE reading_types.value = 'soc'
ORDER BY 1
```

which gets me :

```
| reading_time | reading_type | reading_value |  qikpac_id | 
2021-05-30 09:10:33 +1000   soc     49  13
2021-05-30 09:16:33 +1000   soc     49  14
2021-05-30 09:24:33 +1000   soc     49  15
2021-05-30 09:35:33 +1000   soc     49  16
2021-05-30 09:48:33 +1000   soc     49  13
2021-05-30 09:55:33 +1000   soc     49  14
2021-05-30 10:06:33 +1000   soc     49  15
2021-05-30 10:19:33 +1000   soc     49  16
```

Thanks,
I'm very stuck.. :)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that searches for Blazer below is the answer:

You need to order by :
3 columns - timestamp, string, numeric

And Blazer is very strict on the order and type or you'll get nowhere fast like I did.

```
--      3 columns - timestamp, string, numeric
SELECT
date_trunc('minute', battery_readings.reading_time)::timestamp AS minute,
qikpacs.serial_number as Qikpac,
reading_values.value as Reading_Value

FROM reading_values
INNER JOIN reading_types
ON reading_values.reading_type_id = reading_types.id
JOIN battery_statuses
ON reading_values.battery_status_id = battery_statuses.id
JOIN battery_readings
ON reading_values.battery_reading_id = battery_readings.id
JOIN qikpacs
ON battery_readings.qikpac_id = qikpacs.id
WHERE reading_types.value = 'soc'
AND ( qikpacs.serial_number = 'QP016' )
GROUP BY battery_readings.reading_time,  qikpacs.serial_number, reading_values.value
ORDER BY battery_readings.reading_time,  qikpacs.serial_number, reading_values.value
```

[image of graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qh1CN.png)